# Poly wallpaper creation plugin for gimp or inkscape

Tags: vector-graphics, graphic-design

I use gimp and inkscape to create a few wallpapers.

I would like to know if there are any plugins to edit pictures or new files to create result as shown below.

The plugins might be of gimp or inkscape.

I might be well with any other FOSS app or with a little resentment freeware.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Newer version of inkscape has the Voronoi / Delaunay Triangulation plug in which takes input in form of paths and joins them to form triangles which lead to the poly-wallpaper like look.

Here are a few exaples.

[image]

[The new plugin](https://inkscape.org/en/gallery/item/4190/)